# Tune the following query for better performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

Please help me to tune this sql server query. Here `vcompanyquicksearch` is a view on the `company` table.

What indexes should I create?  A sort operation is taking place in the execution plan
 which costs 24%  i.e.,

```
 [CCEP_DEV].[dbo].[Company].vchContactFirstName Descending,
 [CCEP_DEV].[dbo].[Company].iCompanyId Ascending
```

I don't know why the second sorting is taking place... can anyone suggest why?

```
select top *
 from vCompanyquicksearch 

LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceParameters r1
                    on  vCompanyquicksearch.iCompanyTypeCode  = r1.iParameterId AND
          r1.iSiteId =1

LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceParameters r2
                    on  vCompanyquicksearch.iCompanySubTypeCode = r2.iParameterId AND
          r2.iSiteId =1

LEFT OUTER JOIN ReferenceParameters r3
                    on  vCompanyquicksearch.iPhoneTypeId = r3.iParameterId AND
          r3.iSiteId =1

LEFT OUTER JOIN Country c ON
                    vCompanyquicksearch.chCountryCode        = c.chCountryCode       AND
                    ISNULL(vCompanyquicksearch.chCountryCode,'''') <> '''' and
           c.iSiteId = 1

LEFT OUTER JOIN Region r ON
                    vCompanyquicksearch.chCountryCode        = r.chCountryCode       AND
                    ISNULL(vCompanyquicksearch.chCountryCode,'''') <> ''''  AND
                    vCompanyquicksearch.chRegionCode        = r.chRegionCode       AND
                    ISNULL(vCompanyquicksearch.chRegionCode,'''') <> '''' and
          r.iSiteId = 1

where vCompanyquicksearch.isiteid = 1 and vCompanyquicksearch.tirecordstatus = 1 and vCompanyquicksearch.iCompanyId in (

select distinct * from (

select customer_id from csu_customer_policy
    inner join csu_policy on csu_policy.policy_number = csu_customer_policy.policy_number
    and csu_policy.data_source = csu_customer_policy.data_source
    where csu_policy.vehicle_no in(
'sgv3976r')
  and csu_customer_policy.delete_status = 0 and csu_customer_policy.site_id = ' 1 '
) yTable
) Order by vchName desc
```

Comment: Is `vCompanyquicksearch` some kind of view? Beacuse `Company` it not even in your query, yet it is part of your execution plan.

Comment: My first task when optimising any query is looking at the JOINs and trying to remove any function usage on them as these prevent index utilisation. I would look at country and region JOINs. Second task is to look at any DISTINCTs and remove them where possible as these do sorts that are often not needed. Third task is check to see if all WHERE clauses are optimised like the use of INs where '=' works, again to ensure better index usage.

Comment: hi René Wolferink....as i mentioned in my firt line of question "vcompanyquicksearch is a view on the company table."please suggest :)

Comment: Hi Steph Locke...can you please apply those changes to the query i posted,bcz i am little poor in query handling, thanks in advance :):)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM ReferenceParameters r
    WHERE r.iSiteId = 1
)
SELECT /*TOP*/ *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.vCompanyquicksearch c1 --<-- I think the main problem in this view
    WHERE c1.isiteid = 1 
        AND c1.tirecordstatus = 1  
) c1
LEFT JOIN cte r1 ON c1.iCompanyTypeCode = r1.iParameterId
LEFT JOIN cte r2 ON c1.iCompanySubTypeCode = r2.iParameterId
LEFT JOIN cte r3 ON c1.iPhoneTypeId = r3.iParameterId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Country c
    WHERE c.iSiteId = 1
) c ON c1.chCountryCode = c.chCountryCode 
    AND ISNULL(c1.chCountryCode, '') != ''
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.Region r
    WHERE r.iSiteId = 1
) r ON c1.chCountryCode = r.chCountryCode 
        AND c1.chRegionCode = r.chRegionCode 
        AND ISNULL(c1.chCountryCode, '') != ''  
        AND ISNULL(c1.chRegionCode,'') != '' 
WHERE c1.iCompanyId IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
    FROM dbo.csu_customer_policy p
    JOIN dbo.csu_policy pc ON pc.policy_number = p.policy_number
        AND pc.data_source = p.data_source
    WHERE pc.vehicle_no = 'sgv3976r'
      AND p.delete_status = 0 
      AND p.site_id = ' 1 '
)
ORDER BY vchName DESC
```

**Update:**

```
...
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT TOP ... *
    FROM dbo.vCompanyquicksearch c1
    WHERE c1.isiteid = 1 
        AND c1.tirecordstatus = 1
    ORDER BY vchName DESC  
) c1
...
WHERE c1.iCompanyId IN 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT customer_id 
    FROM dbo.csu_customer_policy p
    JOIN dbo.csu_policy pc ON pc.policy_number = p.policy_number
        AND pc.data_source = p.data_source
    WHERE pc.vehicle_no = 'sgv3976r'
      AND p.delete_status = 0 
      AND p.site_id = ' 1 '
)
```

Comment: hi devart....thanks for your reply but its taking 24% cost for sorting(because of 'distinct' and 'order by'), how come we can reduce dat? i created all the required indices on all the columns required, evry index seek takes 7% cost out of 9 seconds(along with execution plan generation)and total query cost is 100%, how come we reduce these costs further? please suggest me, thanks in advance

Comment: Try to remove ORDER BY + TOP in `vCompanyquicksearch` subquery.

Comment: hi devart...actually that view "vCompanyquicksearch" is taking nearly 10 minutes for execution,i have a doubt,will that view executes every time i run this query(every time i retreieve the data from this view) or will it be static? does the execution time of that view has any effect on this? please guide me if i am wrong,thanks :):), no i cannot remove them i need those, please suggest if i can do the same in any other better way :)